Unable to activate Sanskrit hyphenation using polyglossia
test code:
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[
a5paper,
margin=1.5cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[]{Brill}
\newfontfamily{\latinfont}{Brill}
% \newfontfamily{\latinfont}{Linux Libertine}

\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Serif Devanagari} % Or any other Devanagari font
\usepackage[Devanagari,Latin]{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionTo{Devanagari}{\devanagarifont}
\setTransitionFrom{Devanagari}{\latinfont}
\setTransitionsForDevanagari{\devanagarifont}{\latinfont}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[script=Devanagari]{sanskrit}

\begin{document}

युष्मदस्मत्प्रत्ययगोचरयोर्विषयविषयिणोः तमःप्रकाशवद् विरुद्धस्वभावयोः इतरेतरभावानुपपत्तौ सिद्धायां, तद्धर्माणा-मपि सुतरामितरेतरभावानुपपत्तिः; इत्यतः अस्मत्प्रत्ययगोचरे विषयिणि चिदात्मके युष्मत्प्रत्ययगोचरस्य विषयस्य तद्धर्माणां चाध्यासः, तद्विपर्ययेण विषयिणस्तद्धर्माणां च विषयेऽध्यासो मिथ्येति भवितुं युक्तम् ॥


अत्र ब्रह्मज्ञानार्थं विचारः करणीयः इत्युक्त्या (१) तज्ज्ञानमेव परमपुरुषार्थप्राप्तिं प्रति हेतुत्वेन सूचयन् सूत्रकारः (२) स्वात्मभूतब्रह्मप्राप्ति-रेव परमपुरुषार्थः, (३) तत्प्राप्तिश्च मिथ्याज्ञानव्यवधाननिबर्हणद्वारा -- इति अर्थात् सूचयति । न हि अन्यज्ञानादन्यप्राप्तिरुपपद्यते । न च स्वरूपप्राप्तिर्नाम मिथ्याज्ञानाध्यस्तव्यवधानहानव्यतिरिक्तेन मार्गान्तरेणेति ।

\end{document}

Unable to understand the reason.


Just switching the font doesn't change the current language.
The ucharclasses package might be good for short text inserts, where hyphenation plays no role. For longer passages of text it's much better to use polyglossia environments.
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[
  a5paper,
  margin=1.5cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Brill}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Sanskrit 2003}[
  Script=Devanagari
]

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[script=Devanagari]{sanskrit}

\begin{document}

This part is in English, using Brill

\begin{otherlanguage*}{sanskrit}
युष्मदस्मत्प्रत्ययगोचरयोर्विषयविषयिणोः तमःप्रकाशवद् विरुद्धस्वभावयोः इतरेतरभावानुपपत्तौ सिद्धायां, तद्धर्माणा-मपि सुतरामितरेतरभावानुपपत्तिः; इत्यतः अस्मत्प्रत्ययगोचरे विषयिणि चिदात्मके युष्मत्प्रत्ययगोचरस्य विषयस्य तद्धर्माणां चाध्यासः, तद्विपर्ययेण विषयिणस्तद्धर्माणां च विषयेऽध्यासो मिथ्येति भवितुं युक्तम् ॥

अत्र ब्रह्मज्ञानार्थं विचारः करणीयः इत्युक्त्या (१) तज्ज्ञानमेव परमपुरुषार्थप्राप्तिं प्रति हेतुत्वेन सूचयन् सूत्रकारः (२) स्वात्मभूतब्रह्मप्राप्ति-रेव परमपुरुषार्थः, (३) तत्प्राप्तिश्च मिथ्याज्ञानव्यवधाननिबर्हणद्वारा -- इति अर्थात् सूचयति । न हि अन्यज्ञानादन्यप्राप्तिरुपपद्यते । न च स्वरूपप्राप्तिर्नाम मिथ्याज्ञानाध्यस्तव्यवधानहानव्यतिरिक्तेन मार्गान्तरेणेति ।
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}


